# Problem with SelectionMove in stylesheets

Tags: stylesheet, selectionmove

I would like to design a cell style, for inclusion in a stylesheet, having the following characteristics:

1. It should be a cascade descendant of Text, called here FactoidText
2. When a FactoidText cell is created, it should look exactly like a TextCell (that is, it should be empty) except that its contents should be surrounded by "**{Factoid:** " and "**}**"
3. The typing cursor should be placed just to the right of the space after the colon
4. "**{Factoid:** " and "**}**" should not be editable
5. I wish to avoid solutions with CellFrame and with CellDingbat

An example of use would be the following:

**{Factoid:** Isaac Newton invented the pet door, which he called a "cat flap".**}**

I have made good progress building this style cell but run into a problem with requirement #3, placing the typing cursor. Here is the style definition I have constructed:

```
Cell[
StyleData["FactoidText", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]], 
 CellDynamicExpression :> (
  SetOptions[EvaluationCell[], CellDynamicExpression -> None]; 
  SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, CellContents, 
    AutoScroll -> False];
  NotebookWrite[
   EvaluationNotebook[], 
   TextData[
    StyleBox["{Factoid: ", FontWeight -> Bold, Editable -> False]]
  ];
  NotebookWrite[
   EvaluationNotebook[], 
   TextData[
    StyleBox["\[SelectionPlaceholder]", FontColor -> Red, 
      FontWeight -> Plain, Editable -> True]]
  ];
  NotebookWrite[
   EvaluationNotebook[], 
   TextData[
    StyleBox["}", FontColor -> Black, FontWeight -> Bold, 
      Editable -> False]]
  ];
  SelectionMove[EvaluationNotebook[], After, CellContents, 
    AutoScroll -> False];
 ),
 MenuSortingValue -> 101
]
```

(Note that in the above style definition, the SelectionPlaceholder and the Red styling are there for debugging/visibility purposes and are not part of the requirements.)

When I place the above FactoidText cell in a Notebook's stylesheet and create a FactoidText cell, I see the desired content, but the cursor is not placed correctly. If the creation is initiated from the inter-cell (Choose a new cell type) dropdown, the cursor is placed just before the "**{**" in "**{Factoid:** ". If instead, the cell creation is initiated from the Format/Text menu, the cursor is placed after the closing "**}**".

There are two other small anomalies that I have not been able to fix. 1) If I manually place the cursor before the SelectionPlaceholder and enter some text, the text comes out in bold black rather than in Red. 2) In the same circumstances the typed text can't be deleted. If instead I type after the SelectionPlaceholder, the text is Red and can be successfully deleted, as expected.

Note that I am able to successfully move the insertion point using SelectionMove from the Notebook interface as demonstrated with these expressions:

```
nb = CreateDocument[{Cell["Text 1"], Cell["Text 2"], Cell["Text 3"]}];
Row[{
  Button["Next", SelectionMove[nb, Next, Cell]], 
  Button["Previous", SelectionMove[nb, Previous, Cell]], 
  Button["After", SelectionMove[nb, After, Cell]], 
  Button["Before", SelectionMove[nb, Before, Cell]]
}]
```

I have tried various alternative approaches using other SelectionMove parameters and TemplateBoxes, without success. I feel that others must have developed similar "enclosed" styles, but this is my first attempt with stylesheets, so I welcome any suggestions.

I am running MMA version 13.2.1.0 on a MacBook M2 Pro, with Ventura 13.2.1. This is the only style cell in the spreadsheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would approach the problem by using `TemplateBox` for the wrapper text, together with the following:

```
Cell[
  StyleData["FactoidText", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
  CellDynamicExpression:>(NotebookWrite[
    EvaluationCell[], 
    Cell[
     BoxData[
      TemplateBox[{
        Replace[NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]],{Cell["","FactoidText"]->"\[Placeholder]",cell_:>Cell[First[cell],"Text","Text"]}]
      }, ""]], "FactoidTextHelper"], All]; 
  FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationNotebook[], "MovePrevious"]; 
  FrontEndTokenExecute[EvaluationNotebook[], "MovePrevious"];),
  MenuSortingValue->10000
 ]

Cell[
 StyleData["FactoidTextHelper", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
 Selectable -> False,
 TemplateBoxOptions -> {
   DisplayFunction -> (RowBox[{"{Factoid:", 
        StyleBox[#, Selectable -> True], "}"}] &),
   BaseStyle -> "Text"
   },
 StyleMenuListing -> None
]
```

[image]

Notes:

- This uses the fact that for `TemplateBox`, the default editing behavior is exactly what we want: We can edit the placeholder content, but not the `TemplateBox` itself
- I make the cell contents themselves unselectable, and only enable it selectively for the user content
- I use `All` in `NotebookWrite` to have a controlled starting point for the selection (namely the entire cell), from which I can move to the placeholder using two `"MovePrevious"` actions (this is equivalent to pressing the left arrow key twice). Ideally, I would have used `Placeholder` as the target selection for `NotebookWrite`, but that doesn't work for me for some reason
- I use a helper style `"FactoidTextHelper"` for the actual styling. The main style only created the necessary cell contents. This makes sure that the `CellDynamicExpression` is only triggered once (since the cell style is different after the initial evaluation), otherwise it's very easy to trigger infinite loops.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It provides much insight into how to attack my problem. I have several follow-up questions in subsequent comments.

Comment: The big difference between your solution and my approach was that you used FrontEndTokenExecute["MovePrevious"] and I used SelectionMove. Can you say anything about why yours worked and mine didn't? Does it have anything to do with using the front end vs. using the kernel?

Comment: When I create a FactoidText cell from the notebook's inter-cell "Choose new cell type" dropdown, the entire new cell is selected instead of having just the PlaceHolder selected, as with your animation. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this or why the two forms of cell creation behave differently?

Comment: When I save the notebook containing the newly created FactoidText cell, exit, and then reopen it, the FactoidText cell is pink. I have to open the stylesheet and perform Show Expression on the style cell before the FactoidText cell re-expresses itself correctly. Do you know why this happens? Is there a way around it?

Comment: @SpencerRugaber Regarding `"MovePrevious"` vs. `SelectionMove`: I find it very hard to ever use `SelectionMove` effectively. Here for instance, my quick attempts didn't manage to ever move the selection to the left. `"MovePrevious"` on the other hand behaves exactly as if you pressed the Left key on your keyboard, which does work as expected. As for the code not working when using the "Choose new cell type" dropdown: It should work now. The issue was that the `"MovePrevious"` was performed in the dialog notebook instead of the one with the cell, which is fixed now.

Comment: @SpencerRugaber As for the pink cell issue: At least from a quick test, I could not reproduce the issue. Can you share a screenshot of how it looks like? Does the pink box have a tooltip? What version are you using?

Comment: I ran into two issues wrt your fix: 1) When I made your changes in my embedded stylesheet, they worked for two of the three methods for inserting a new FactoidText cell. Specifically, they worked for Right-Click FactoidText and "Format/Style FactoidText". But when I tried "+ Choose a new cell type FactoidText", the Placeholder was not selected.

Comment: 2)  More fundamentally, FactoidText did not work at all when I installed the stylesheet. In particular, I took the FactoidText and FactoidTextHelper cells and exported them to $UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/Stylesheets/MyStyles.nb. This stylesheet shows up successfully when I do "Format/Stylesheet/MyStyles", but selecting this choice does not make FactoidText available when I try any of the three cell creation approaches that I mentioned in the previous comment. Have you tried your approach with an installed stylesheet?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply... For 1: I made some more changes, it should work now in more circumstances. Note that using the style as "inline" style is not supported, so when using "Format > Style > FactoidText", you have to make sure that the entire cell is selected. It now also attempts to preseve the existing cell contents. The only thing that is not working yet is the new notebook toolbar: When adding the cell via that menu, the placeholder is not selected. So far, I don't know why exactly.

Comment: For 2: Did you save the notebook containing the stylesheet, or the stylesheet itself? I did the latter, and it works as expected when using the installed sheet.

Comment: I have now been able to successfully and use the stylesheet. I still have the problem with the "+ Insert Cell" option for creating a Factoid. However, I have run into a more serious problem: When I paste in text containing multiple lines, some of the lines begin with four extra spaces, and the previous lines do not fill sufficiently. Can you try constructing a multi-line Factoid and see if you see this behavior? Do you have any suggestions for how to mitigate the problem. Thx.