# Problem extend the Text style

Tags: text, stylesheet

This question follows up on a previous question [SelectionMove in Stylesheets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/287621/problem-with-selectionmove-in-stylesheets) that essentially asked to how to construct a new style that was the same as a "Text" paragraph except that the contents of the paragraph were bracketed. In that question, the beginning bracket was "**{Factoid:** " and the ending bracket was "**}**", but the given solution can be easily adapted to other brackets.

Unfortunately, there were several problems with the solution as illustrated in the following example. Here is a paragraph of text as taken from a Text cell:

[image]

**Edit:** Here are the corresponding box contents:

[image]

And here is a version using the style from the previous answer:

[image]

(I have used images to avoid Markdown reformatting.)

**Edit:** Here are the corresponding box contents:

[image]

Note that the both the second-line indent and the right-end fill are different. Experiments indicate that the text inside the new style has other problems: commas or semicolons sometimes cause line breaks; "5%" gets converted to "5x%" where the "x" is in light gray indicating implicit multiplication; etc.

I have solved some of these problems by adding options to the style definition:

```
TextAlignment->Left,
AutoMultiplicationSymbol->{},
LineIndent->0
```

However, they don't solve the short-right-end problem. I have looked through all of my option settings, and they are identical for both paragraphs:

[image]

The only anomaly is the value of -9998 for PageWidth. I have tried manually changing this to WindowWidth, but nothing changed. So my tactical question is "How can I get the line length for the bracketed paragraph be the same as the for built-in paragraph?" The more general issue is why is the new style different at all when it is a simple extension to Text? Shouldn't there be some option values that are different? Why did I have to make the option additions that I did?

I am running Mathematica 13.2.1 on a MacBook M2, with MacOS Ventura 13.2.1.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide the box contents of the problematic cell, as can be obtained from the menu item Cell | Show Expression.

Comment: My guess is that the Cell is an "Input" cell, and not a "Text" cell, which is why the formatting doesn't follow "Text" guidelines.

Comment: @Carl Woll: I have added the box contents. I don't see anything about "Input", but I do notice the use of nested RowBoxes. I am unsure how RowBox makes its decisions on partitioning its contents. Any thoughts or workarounds?